# Using long strings with wcout, Simple "Hello World" doesn't works ! ( How do I change the way wcout is opened BINARY or TEXT )

Tags: c++

Essentially the code "Hello World" a little bit modified should be made working correctly

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){ wcout<<L"GoodMorning Καλημέρα"<<endl;return 0; }
```

do I ask too much ? That is the short story !

The long one is: My platform is ubuntu and g++.

As I recently realized streams may be opened in binary or text mode.

When we use wcout to print a wstring the mode should be text mode because the wide character string ( essentially utf32 ) should be converted during the transfer from the stream to the "file" in order to get the code page of the terminal ( actually that "code page" is utf8 - but could be any one e.g. in the specific case ISO8859-7).

So when we use:

```
std::wcout<<L"καλημέρα"<<std::endl;
```

if the mode of wcout is text mode the string gets converted from utf32 (linux - under conditions) or UCS2 string (windows) into the codepage of the terminal (linux utf8) according to the `std::locale::global` or to the imbue used on the stream.

So in order to work with wcout, the mode should be TEXT not BINARY.
But my system opens it in BINARY not TEXT so the text isn't shown correctly.

How do I change the way `wcout` is opened ?

Comment: A string literal prefixed with `L` (like yours) is not UTF32, it's a *wide-character* string, just the way that `std::wcout` wants. A UTF32 string in C++ would have the `U` prefix (see e.g. [Wikipedia on C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#New_string_literals)). And no, you can't change how the standard streams are opened, unless you want to make an incompatible non-standard C++ library?

Comment: It happens that in my system sizeof(wchar_)==sizeof(char32_t). So the data that are written inside the L"καλημέρα" are the unicode code of κ α λ η μ έ ρ α . If it was a windows platform the codes would be the same but in 2 bytes instead than 4. The code above doesn't works in my system ( doesn't shows the correct string ).

Comment: Yes, the size may be the same, but the encoding isn't. Just because two types has the same size doesn't mean that they're the same. String literals prefixed with `L` are wide-character strings, no other encoding no matter the size.

Comment: By the way, have you tried just doing e.g. `std::cout<<"καλημέρα"<<std::endl;`?

Comment: Yes that works, but the strings I have are wstrings not strings. The reason why that works is that the text corresponding to "καλημέρα" is the utf8 conversion of it ( 16 bytes ). C++ doesn't knows anything about it it just transfers that to the terminal that happens to understand the utf8 format.

Answer (score 2):

Text vs. binary mode only controls whether a newline character `'\n'` gets converted to an end of line sequence on systems where text fikes concentionally have and end of line sequence. On POSIX systems text vs. binary mode has no effect. That said, there is no standard way to control text vs. binary mode. On POSIX systems you can probably just replace file descriptor 1. However, doing so will not change the encoding being used at all.

When you feel you need to play tricks with encodings you'll pretty much only get support when using fike streams. If you want to deal with encodings for other streams you'll need to implement your own stream buffer doing conversions.

Comment: My scope is not to do any conversion and to allow the system to do it, that is the most correct way of doing it.

Comment: I checked with two locales and using text mode and I wrote the same String e.g. "καλημέρα" to a file one time using the locale "el_GR.utf8" and the other using "el_GR.ISO8859-7". The result was correct i used gedit and opening the file with utf8 in the first case the file showed correctly ( while using the second encoding to open it each character showed double ). Opening the file written using el_GR.ISO8859-7 with the same encoding the file showed correctly. I didn't knew those tricks of streams and I found them useafull in order to do the least amount of work.

Answer (score 1):

This works nicely for me, using g++ 4.8.1 in some old Ubuntu:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );
    wcout<<L"GoodMorning Καλημέρα"<<endl;
}
```

In Windows you need instead to call `_setmode` (and if using g++, `-U` the no-gcc-extensions-please macro symbol).

---

As Dietmar has already noted, C stream text mode has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Your comments make me insisting on the fact that C++ streams may use un-translated or translated mode. The scope is to be able to convert between the internal wide strings the external codepage. So when you write to the file you are converting the wide string to the external code page (e.g.ISO8859-7 or UTF8).Inversely you may read a file saved in utf-8 format and read it in your wstring just using the read routine without bothering about the conversion between utf8 and utf32. Check it to believe !

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis: we're **not telepaths**, we can't intuit that the problem was really about something totally different from what you presented, namely a problem with output performed before `main`. there are solutions to that (how to adapt this stated problem's solution, to the actual problem). but you need to *ask the question*.

Comment: On linux I found that there must *not be any output* prior to `setlocale(...)`, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I individuated the problem the output was used inside main as follows:

```
int main(){
  std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.utf-8"));
  std::wcout<<L"Ελληνικά"<<std::endl;
```

While the wide printing is among the first instructiosn to use it the output was not correct.
I supposed that maybe somewhere inside the program ( may be initialization routines ) accessed the cout or wcout and so setted it in binary mode.

I changed the includes as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
struct initLocale{
    initLocale(){
        std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.utf-8"));
        std::wcout<<L"Ελληνικά"<<std::endl;
}
```

The scope is to create a dummy variable just after including  with the only scope to output something to wcout in order to be the first to use it.
With that change the output is correct, as soon as I comment out the line `std::wcout<<L"Ελληνικά"<<std::endl;` the output is again wrong.
You may also change `std::wcout<<L"Ελληνικά"<<std::endl;` into `std::wcout<<std::endl` and it works.
While I have solved my problem, that should be pointed out somehow and any way a way the question of how to change the binary or text behaviour of wcout should be found.